# How would you implement and differentiate between input actions and input states?

Tags: libgdx, input, entity-system, entity-component, artemis

Im currently trying to setup my game and Ive started to implement input. It works like this:

I have an `Input` class who notifies the `InputMapper` whenever some key is pressed (or released or whatever). This InputMapper gets the keys pressed and returns an `Action` or a `State` depending on the current `InputContext` (Action and State are enums) (I used [this article](https://www.gamedev.net/blog/355/entry-2250186-designing-a-robust-input-handling-system-for-games/) to get idea of how it should work).

**`Action` here represents one-time actions like `Jump` while `State` represents continuous things like `move_right`.**

I now attach an `InputListener`to the `InputMapper`, which gets the `Action` or `State` whenever pressed.

In the game I use an **entity-component-system**. I have a `ControlComponent`, which should have variables that dictate what an entity should do and a `KeyBoardSystem`, which should set these variables. `ControlComponent` is then used by things like `WalkSystem` or `JumpSystem`.

**My question now is: How would you implement these States and Actions in an entity-component-system?** I know that States could be represented by booleans in the ControlComponent, but Actions? They could be events, but the ControlComponent doesnt (shouldnt?) have any method or know about the systems that use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be useful, but [Unity has an upcoming input system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVbxemkOWew) that seems to have some concepts in common with the article you cited. While Unity's approach isn't a strict ECS (their components have methods), their example might still provide some inspirations for how to break the problem into meaningful components / data objects.

Answer (score 0):

What's the harm in allowing the input state for both actions & state to be managed by the input system directly and you merely expose methods for querying this state from other systems?

Your `JumpSystem` registers the `Jump` action with the `InputSystem`.  Perhaps the registration is also accompanyed by the default key for `SPACE`.  As a step in your game's startup, you load the player's mappings from a file to override the default input mappings with their custom ones.

At some future frame, your `PlayerControllerSystem` queries the `InputSystem` and checks whether the *JUMP* action is active.  If the answer is true, then the player controller system initiates the jump sequence.  This might include setting some booleans in the player controller component.

At the end of the frame, the `InputSystem` clears all actions and sets them back to inactive while leaving the current active status for *States* as-is so that carries over to the next frame.

In other words, I'm advocating polling input rather than pushing it.  Why?

When input is pushed, now each system interested in input should cache those values so that later on when those systems update their state, they can react to that input.  They shouldn't react to the input prior to because each system in the game loop typically must update in a deterministic order.

By polling input instead, we avoid having to force systems to maintain input state when it would be dispatched at the top of the game loop.  Systems interested in current input state can obtain it when its needed for calculations and furthermore it allows that state to be cleared/managed cleanly from frame to frame.

**UPDATE**

I don't believe it makes sense to separate things like keyboard, mouse, and joystick into something called a *system* because these are technically *input devices* which should be managed by a system responsible for *input*.

That is why I mentioned an `InputSystem`, of which your `InputMapper` is a component of.  The mapper is ultimately responsible for turning input events into actions or state changes.

Next, I mentioned `PlayerControllerSystem` because this is where input actions and state changes are translated into game world reactions.  This system knows how to to turn the jump action trigger into a series of changes to game objects so that jump occurs.  This might imply applying a boolean value on a component or coordinating the jump animation with the animation system and the movement/force needed to jump with the physics/movement systems.

Just like components, make sure not to create systems that are equally too granular in nature unless there really is a legit reason to do so.

This is a simplified example of my own engine:

```
class PlayerControllerSystem {
public:
  PlayerControllerSystem(InputSystem* pInput) {
    // Register an action in the category 'Movement' called 'Jump'
    // Assign the action to respond to the default key SPACE.
    mJumpAction = pInput->registerAction( "Movement", "Jump", Input::KC_SPACE );

    // Register a state in the category 'Movement' called 'Move Forward'
    // Assign the state to respond to the default key W.
    mForwardState = pInput->registerState( "Movement", "Move Forward", Input::KC_W );
    ....
  }

  void update(const FrameEvent& evt) {
    if ( mJumpAction.isActive() ) { 
      // initiate jump
    }
    if ( mForwardState.isActive() ) {
      // handle forward movement 
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am not using events nor the observer pattern here.  I believe its more efficient to simply have the input system gather and set state rather than dispatch to callbacks.  There are most definitely places in your game loop where both synchronous and asynchronous events are useful, but I honestly do not believe that it makes sense to use them for input.

The system above shows how it tells the input system when the spacebar is pressed, toggle the mJumpAction as active.  Internally, the input system maintains a data structure that relates `Input::KC_SPACE` as an action with the name `Jump` and category `Movement`.

What is the importance of this name/category?  I use it to manage a tree display of category and named key mapping options users can change in a GUI screen inside the game.

During the update loop of that system, it uses the `mJumpAction` and `mForwardState` variables to check whether they're toggled.

Now your implementation of the input system might not return anything to the calling system if you'd rather not have variables.  If so, all you simply need to do during the update loop would be to do something like:

```
if ( pInputSystem->isActionActive( "Jump" ) ) {
  // do jump logic
}
```

I prefer the variable approach for two reasons:

1. I avoid having to use strings to lookup things during the update loop.
2. I can have the input system return the same action/state should multiple systems register the same named/key-combo configuration and save memory.

Lastly, the input system registration could also be written to accept a sequence of values allowing for console game type reactions, like:

```
`A`, `A`, `B`, `Up`, `Down`, `Left`, `Right`.
```

Much like how the input system determines when the key/state has been activated and sets it accordingly, the same holds true for sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think Im confused. So I think you mean the `KeyboardSystem` with `PlayerControllerSystem`, right? Also I dont have an `InputSystem`, but rather the `InputMapper`, which converts raw input into actions and states. How would you implement your registration approach, would you do it with a simple Observer pattern and events, and how would you store the states and actions for the systems to be polled, simple arrays where a system would have to call `if(activeInput.contains(JUMP)) //do stuff`? Sorry if its obvious, just want to fully get your approach.

Comment: @zebleckDAMM Please see my update to my post wrt your questions.